# How to install Tomcat in Amazon Web Services EC2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, tomcat8

I have created an instance in Amazon web services, and I have connected to the server using putty through ssh.

But I do not know how to install tomcat 8 in amazon ec2. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use yum tool to install the tomcat8 packer from amazon default repository.

The command is: `yum install tomcat8-webapps tomcat8-admin-webapps`

Answer (score 15):

On Amazon Linux 2 AMI:

1. List extra packages (you will see tomcat8 versions):

   `$ amazon-linux-extras list`
2. Install extra packages:

   `$ sudo amazon-linux-extras install tomcat8.5`
3. Start tomcat service:

   `$ sudo systemctl start tomcat`
4. Create index file:

```
    $ cd /usr/share/tomcat/webapps
    $ sudo mkdir ROOT
    $ cd ROOT/
    $ sudo vi index.html #add some HTML content
```

Next you could view your site at `localhost:8080`

Answer (score 9):

For Amazon AMI 2, Tomcat is available in Amazon Linux Extra topic "tomcat8.5"

To use, run

```
# sudo amazon-linux-extras install tomcat8.5
```

Learn more at
https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/faqs/#Amazon_Linux_Extras

Answer (score 6):

If you also want to know the help documentation, the command is:
**sudo yum install tomcat8-webapps tomcat8-docs-webapp tomcat8-admin-webapps**

Answer (score 2):

The below Link works well for EC2 / Linux or Mac

```
sudo yum install tomcat8-webapps tomcat8-docs-webapp tomcat8-admin-webapps
```

This will install:

1. WebApps Folder
2. Tomcat documentation (Gives local documentation for qucik reference)
3. Admin App : through which you can install / export / start /stop / reload an application (without having to login)

Note: When a Manager App is installed - be sure to change the default roles and permissions etc and Password too. Otherwise you are very vulnerable. Its best to disable the admin module for better security.

Answer (score 2):

STEPS:

1. first check whether java has to be installed on your instance or not.
2. if not, install java: `yum install java -y`
3. go to the tomcat-Apache.org site, and copy the link to the tar.gz file
4. open the terminal and execute this command: `sudo wget <tar.gz path>`
5. unzip the tar file: `tar -vxzf Apache-tomcat-xxxx.tar.gz`
6. setup users and port number (by default 8080)
7. then shutdown and start the tomcat server: `./shutdown.sh` and `./startup.sh`

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo su
amazon-linux-extras install tomcat9
systemctl start tomcat
systemctl status tomcat
```

Comment: @MattAndruff There's no link here, and code-only answers are valid answers.

Answer (score 1):

For this:

1. you need to do copy the tomcat tar file path `wget <tar file path>`
2. unzip the tar file `tar -zvxf apache-tomcat-xxxx.tar.zf`
3. you need to set the users and port number and then stop and restart the tomcat server

Answer (score 1):

below mentioned follow the step but http://locathost:8080/manager/html is Not open on amazon Linux error is showing in the as below menitoned

(HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/manager/html] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.41)

amazon-linux-extras

amazon-linux-extras install tomcat9

yum update

systemctl start tomcat

systemctl status tomcat

netstat -tunple

cd /usr/share/tomcat/webapps

mkdir ROOT

cd ROOT/

vi index.html